# Removing a " from the end of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am passing a variable such as "box_1" (Including the quote marks) which is stored in the function as the variable box to a function which will animate said box, however I need a complete function to come after the animation which works on ("box_1 .title") So what I want to do is take the " off of the end of the variable passed to the function and then use (box + '.title"') I can't find an easy answer to this online, so I thought I'd ask here :)

Comment: Constructing jQuery selectors w/ concatenation is a really bad idea.  What have you been given, and what are you trying to select?

Comment: could you please post your code and possibly rephrase what you need to accomplish? it's very confusing to see from 4 lines of ongoing text

Comment: Is box_1 an id or anything? WHy do you need the quotes?

Comment: Yes it's an id, I need the quotes because I'm using it as a selector... Ohhhh actually may have this solved, give me a second before I bother giving more info

Comment: If I had explained everything I wanted to do it would have taken hours, the reason I was so vague is because all I wanted to know was how to remove a '"' from the end of a string... simples

Comment: Are you passing in this as the variable: "\"box_1\"" or this: "box_1". If it is the second then the quotes aren't part of the data stored in your variable. They just declare the type as a string.

Comment: Ok turns out I was being stupid firebug had shown me that the passed variable was "box_1" so I assumed it had literally passed "box_1" With quotes as the variable... turns out it hadn't so I had no need for doing this, sorry for wasting all your time :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `$(given_selector_string).find('.title')` is what you're looking for?

Comment: That's the ideal solution thank you! Hadn't even thought of getting around it using .find()!

Comment: Although your selector string shouldn't be surrounded by quotes in this case. I'm beginning to doubt it ever was.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real issue is that you are storing "s in your variable name. You don't need those for the selector. The only reason you need the quotes in something like $(".title") is to declare .title as a string. Your string should not contain quotes. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n5htY/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chop off the last `"` & concatenate;

```
id = id.substr(0, id.length - 1) + " .title\""​​​​​​​​;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the final character?

```
box.substring(0, box.length-1);
```